# Failed to validate self-signed certificate with python-requests

Tags: python, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I try to access a self signed web server with python  requests. While everything works (firefox, openssl), my python program  still fail to validate the certificate.

For testing the certificate works I use:

> openssl s_client -CAfile selfsigned.xython.fr.crt -servername fqdn -connect selfsigned.xython.fr:443

openssl accept the certificate with this command.
If I omit the CAfile option, openssl normaly said its self-signed

Now the python script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
import OpenSSL
import ssl
url = 'https://selfsigned.xython.fr'
verify = 'selfsigned.xython.fr.crt'
try:
    r = requests.get(url, verify=verify)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    cert = ssl.get_server_certificate(('selfsigned.xython.fr', 443))
    print(cert)
    cert = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert)
    print(cert.get_issuer())
    print(cert.get_subject().get_components())
    print(e)
```

The exception is

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='selfsigned.xython.fr', port=443): Max retries exceeded with
> url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, "[SSL:
> CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch,
> certificate is not valid for 'selfsigned.xython.fr'. (_ssl.c:1010)")))

But all cert.get_xxx show me the right selfsigned.xython.fr
So there is only requests which dont like my certificate, but I do not find why.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

openssl x509 -in selfsigned.xython.fr.crt -text

```
> Certificate:
>     Data:
>         Version: 3 (0x2)
>         Serial Number:
>             4d:c7:6b:52:3f:6a:6a:04:a2:ca:4e:81:2b:77:ba:7c:ad:97:08:fe
>         Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
>         Issuer: C = FR, ST = France, L = Paris, O = xython, OU = tests, CN = selfsigned.xython.fr
>         Validity
>             Not Before: Aug 28 16:56:03 2023 GMT
>             Not After : Aug 25 16:56:03 2033 GMT
>         Subject: C = FR, ST = France, L = Paris, O = xython, OU = tests, CN = selfsigned.xython.fr
>         Subject Public Key Info:
>             Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
>                 RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
>                 Modulus:
>                     00:d8:07:80:ff:f2:d1:ae:79:14:a0:22:e7:31:a6:
>                     47:ab:3b:ab:ee:fb:9a:a9:b8:49:5a:05:a8:64:60:
>                     bf:d4:64:21:13:ec:ba:89:08:df:1e:0f:8a:88:8e:
>                     5c:16:8f:3f:e1:ab:df:57:88:30:69:20:b5:bb:f1:
>                     8c:ee:f4:a4:8d:36:9b:4e:4b:b2:df:90:f6:ad:ac:
>                     b2:1a:d5:13:dd:8a:f9:e5:a0:65:0c:0e:47:78:f5:
>                     90:2d:7c:05:d3:81:69:bf:c6:a8:70:9b:c7:aa:4e:
>                     fe:42:13:57:eb:d9:6c:d9:68:8d:ec:83:7e:1f:15:
>                     e8:6a:c5:51:f2:4a:3a:26:43:44:a5:7f:89:8d:f0:
>                     d5:6c:67:b8:91:33:87:a1:e1:ce:7d:03:4b:16:22:
>                     92:53:f2:4c:6d:e8:82:d7:e7:51:dd:4a:9d:3a:f1:
>                     11:d1:3a:41:4a:1a:e9:1e:e5:aa:88:78:0a:40:04:
>                     ce:3c:5b:60:62:c6:30:85:42:2a:8f:ab:a3:dc:41:
>                     24:87:7c:04:42:7e:73:93:35:17:a1:a8:1c:df:5b:
>                     a5:63:a9:cf:e8:fa:82:ad:e6:c9:f7:19:65:e0:b3:
>                     19:2b:a5:e0:9e:fb:48:39:ed:4c:3d:f3:fb:de:80:
>                     c4:6f:b0:df:e1:24:e6:aa:96:fb:c2:9c:f0:11:98:
>                     7f:a6:8c:b2:ca:ff:0d:01:4d:17:ef:0e:95:c7:49:
>                     df:26:25:21:da:0c:9e:91:ff:fd:eb:33:11:8b:4b:
>                     95:89:77:4f:e9:6c:4f:61:ef:c0:23:64:8f:b4:81:
>                     e0:ce:80:68:36:ca:fa:e1:de:93:a9:72:74:ae:c5:
>                     63:4d:f6:e8:b0:9f:01:d1:f9:aa:a8:d3:fd:c4:00:
>                     e9:d8:5d:58:3b:d3:e5:82:14:8c:12:0b:b6:09:c6:
>                     24:8f:b2:99:9c:1b:04:40:ee:36:67:78:f8:cd:61:
>                     3e:ae:f6:e5:1e:23:fa:1e:b2:5a:4f:cc:8b:80:09:
>                     fd:cd:c6:b9:15:e4:e5:3f:a8:33:93:be:d3:95:db:
>                     39:46:0f:80:e2:3d:6e:c8:74:b9:4d:93:79:78:8c:
>                     25:f2:43:22:8c:4f:9b:9e:1d:0d:67:92:a8:a6:6b:
>                     6c:80:b6:b3:0d:61:13:6e:79:52:8e:72:50:9d:97:
>                     01:e5:d7:9a:2a:b0:87:32:4f:04:d2:48:69:b1:28:
>                     73:c0:29:4b:3a:2b:fb:b4:ff:f9:fc:5b:93:40:54:
>                     14:4b:73:8d:b8:16:5e:72:3b:89:92:9d:35:98:ce:
>                     30:f6:ed:99:cc:16:6a:8b:29:9a:b3:fa:56:2e:27:
>                     7f:57:3e:5a:8f:45:e3:47:a4:cc:1b:23:15:d2:9b:
>                     76:20:47
>                 Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
>         X509v3 extensions:
>             X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
>                 35:1A:EF:44:C7:C3:2C:70:AE:EB:AE:97:25:F6:2D:5E:9F:B9:8A:79
>             X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
>                 keyid:35:1A:EF:44:C7:C3:2C:70:AE:EB:AE:97:25:F6:2D:5E:9F:B9:8A:79
> 
>             X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
>                 CA:TRUE
>     Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
>          c3:0c:e1:f8:7b:0c:28:d8:4f:73:41:d2:58:2e:43:b3:88:d6:
>          dc:f0:d6:ed:78:fb:15:db:47:81:cb:20:a7:63:f3:1a:47:d8:
>          e1:07:62:ac:75:af:f9:1b:bc:06:29:2b:97:0c:d7:4f:23:f9:
>          a0:d5:9b:8b:22:72:8f:f5:05:21:d4:0b:35:f3:06:2f:46:f0:
>          5a:4d:da:17:a0:a3:70:54:7a:31:ad:81:6a:16:ce:a7:19:fb:
>          ba:fb:44:9b:d2:b2:83:94:af:94:f3:30:16:b9:da:a8:d5:21:
>          6b:b5:f8:b6:29:a8:96:ef:c5:41:8b:96:10:43:43:46:fd:8c:
>          5e:a1:b7:df:e7:cc:78:83:0b:d1:76:b3:4d:e2:e4:2d:24:c3:
>          c2:6e:fc:ae:b6:9e:d1:a1:d6:0c:72:c0:cf:f4:a9:d7:d9:0a:
>          e1:4f:7f:d0:3c:7e:75:f0:eb:66:2d:a0:f1:6b:7a:4d:59:a3:
>          02:0e:8e:be:71:61:13:af:d9:ac:60:9d:67:2f:d7:44:08:2d:
>          41:01:95:66:6c:ac:69:0c:2d:11:c4:e8:55:c3:03:59:e9:17:
>          fd:57:91:f6:ba:d3:16:21:e8:e0:ff:8d:5e:c3:40:d4:a7:b6:
>          67:76:05:97:ba:2c:2d:6b:10:63:46:89:fb:d1:4b:0b:ac:62:
>          80:61:fb:78:7e:fd:51:70:58:77:f3:d4:5f:ae:2c:3b:7b:14:
>          46:07:96:85:ce:ff:0f:1d:8a:0d:12:26:f9:e2:e5:6e:12:89:
>          80:46:bd:d4:51:4b:3d:93:25:44:24:22:22:55:03:0d:0b:ee:
>          9c:1a:86:9f:49:13:5a:57:e9:af:54:b1:b3:d1:16:e9:4e:03:
>          73:a7:29:87:3c:3b:1f:6c:a4:97:c3:dc:95:79:2c:73:50:5a:
>          a9:4d:68:37:24:0b:27:84:8f:eb:4a:c5:a8:f2:a8:a7:c7:be:
>          4a:57:9d:aa:82:a2:b1:e4:e9:e5:11:5f:14:30:8c:74:3e:ca:
>          46:d1:ab:23:cd:28:8d:9a:be:56:8d:59:6a:dd:58:ac:54:0a:
>          34:36:d8:ba:ba:7f:22:d5:10:a2:f5:af:a5:c8:41:ee:9f:84:
>          ef:4d:d3:63:ee:af:14:f4:f6:ec:15:29:2e:81:4e:75:81:2b:
>          ca:b7:1e:12:48:7f:f3:ca:50:19:ac:70:52:76:94:46:5c:f2:
>          ca:fd:b2:11:70:3c:6d:6d:12:2a:dd:aa:13:21:a5:27:d8:4d:
>          ab:ee:61:32:d3:04:67:45:1b:b9:d4:e1:c7:ee:f7:cf:fb:4e:
>          80:56:bf:f7:79:bf:87:cd:4e:78:ec:26:9b:54:83:32:2c:1c:
>          77:ee:b0:45:1e:f2:f8:09
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIFvTCCA6WgAwIBAgIUTcdrUj9qagSiyk6BK3e6fK2XCP4wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
> BQAwbjELMAkGA1UEBhMCRlIxDzANBgNVBAgMBkZyYW5jZTEOMAwGA1UEBwwFUGFy
> aXMxDzANBgNVBAoMBnh5dGhvbjEOMAwGA1UECwwFdGVzdHMxHTAbBgNVBAMMFHNl
> bGZzaWduZWQueHl0aG9uLmZyMB4XDTIzMDgyODE2NTYwM1oXDTMzMDgyNTE2NTYw
> M1owbjELMAkGA1UEBhMCRlIxDzANBgNVBAgMBkZyYW5jZTEOMAwGA1UEBwwFUGFy
> aXMxDzANBgNVBAoMBnh5dGhvbjEOMAwGA1UECwwFdGVzdHMxHTAbBgNVBAMMFHNl
> bGZzaWduZWQueHl0aG9uLmZyMIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKC
> AgEA2AeA//LRrnkUoCLnMaZHqzur7vuaqbhJWgWoZGC/1GQhE+y6iQjfHg+KiI5c
> Fo8/4avfV4gwaSC1u/GM7vSkjTabTkuy35D2rayyGtUT3Yr55aBlDA5HePWQLXwF
> 04Fpv8aocJvHqk7+QhNX69ls2WiN7IN+HxXoasVR8ko6JkNEpX+JjfDVbGe4kTOH
> oeHOfQNLFiKSU/JMbeiC1+dR3UqdOvER0TpBShrpHuWqiHgKQATOPFtgYsYwhUIq
> j6uj3EEkh3wEQn5zkzUXoagc31ulY6nP6PqCrebJ9xll4LMZK6XgnvtIOe1MPfP7
> 3oDEb7Df4STmqpb7wpzwEZh/poyyyv8NAU0X7w6Vx0nfJiUh2gyekf/96zMRi0uV
> iXdP6WxPYe/AI2SPtIHgzoBoNsr64d6TqXJ0rsVjTfbosJ8B0fmqqNP9xADp2F1Y
> O9PlghSMEgu2CcYkj7KZnBsEQO42Z3j4zWE+rvblHiP6HrJaT8yLgAn9zca5FeTl
> P6gzk77Tlds5Rg+A4j1uyHS5TZN5eIwl8kMijE+bnh0NZ5KopmtsgLazDWETbnlS
> jnJQnZcB5deaKrCHMk8E0khpsShzwClLOiv7tP/5/FuTQFQUS3ONuBZecjuJkp01
> mM4w9u2ZzBZqiymas/pWLid/Vz5aj0XjR6TMGyMV0pt2IEcCAwEAAaNTMFEwHQYD
> VR0OBBYEFDUa70THwyxwruuulyX2LV6fuYp5MB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFDUa70THwyxw
> ruuulyX2LV6fuYp5MA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggIB
> AMMM4fh7DCjYT3NB0lguQ7OI1tzw1u14+xXbR4HLIKdj8xpH2OEHYqx1r/kbvAYp
> K5cM108j+aDVm4sico/1BSHUCzXzBi9G8FpN2hego3BUejGtgWoWzqcZ+7r7RJvS
> soOUr5TzMBa52qjVIWu1+LYpqJbvxUGLlhBDQ0b9jF6ht9/nzHiDC9F2s03i5C0k
> w8Ju/K62ntGh1gxywM/0qdfZCuFPf9A8fnXw62YtoPFrek1ZowIOjr5xYROv2axg
> nWcv10QILUEBlWZsrGkMLRHE6FXDA1npF/1Xkfa60xYh6OD/jV7DQNSntmd2BZe6
> LC1rEGNGifvRSwusYoBh+3h+/VFwWHfz1F+uLDt7FEYHloXO/w8dig0SJvni5W4S
> iYBGvdRRSz2TJUQkIiJVAw0L7pwahp9JE1pX6a9UsbPRFulOA3OnKYc8Ox9spJfD
> 3JV5LHNQWqlNaDckCyeEj+tKxajyqKfHvkpXnaqCorHk6eURXxQwjHQ+ykbRqyPN
> KI2avlaNWWrdWKxUCjQ22Lq6fyLVEKL1r6XIQe6fhO9N02PurxT09uwVKS6BTnWB
> K8q3HhJIf/PKUBmscFJ2lEZc8sr9shFwPG1tEirdqhMhpSfYTavuYTLTBGdFG7nU
> 4cfu98/7ToBWv/d5v4fNTnjsJptUgzIsHHfusEUe8vgJ
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The key/cert was generated with:

> openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout
> /etc/ssl/apache2/selfsigned.xython.fr.key -out
> /etc/ssl/apache2/selfsigned.xython.fr.crt -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes
> -subj "/C=FR/ST=France/L=Paris/O=xython/OU=tests/CN=selfsigned.xython.fr"

Another EDIT: If someone know from which project came this _ssl.c, it will permit to find what it see instead of the correct fqdn.

EDIT of 29/08/2023
Added output of openssl s_client
openssl s_client -CAfile selfsigned.xython.fr.crt -servername selfsigned.xython.fr -connect selfsigned.xython.fr:443

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = FR, ST = France, L = Paris, O = xython, OU = tests, CN = selfsigned.xython.fr
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = FR, ST = France, L = Paris, O = xython, OU = tests, CN = selfsigned.xython.fr
   i:C = FR, ST = France, L = Paris, O = xython, OU = tests, CN = selfsigned.xython.fr
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=C = FR, ST = France, L = Paris, O = xython, OU = tests, CN = selfsigned.xython.fr

issuer=C = FR, ST = France, L = Paris, O = xython, OU = tests, CN = selfsigned.xython.fr

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-384, 384 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2487 bytes and written 480 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 984E846F5C387BBAC464830BB8300C3811D121B6A5286C1128F2CFEFA85AA0C8
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 463579A7EC740E96F12E156A97F24E6B16DBE9BC34D86740362EF7CFFC5F5D0AD4070FE535E661EAB6D55E18E0C0A01A
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 4a 63 b7 7e ac 2f d5 aa-5c 53 e2 0c a7 b7 56 4a   Jc.~./..\S....VJ
    0010 - 16 8e 1a ce 99 1a b4 19-42 e3 85 aa 37 10 3f 34   ........B...7.?4
    0020 - 07 2b 3c 80 97 89 1d 9e-8b 69 60 e6 7e d4 0d db   .+<......i`.~...
    0030 - f9 e1 40 57 d3 a2 e9 a6-28 6b e9 f8 d9 1c 47 aa   ..@W....(k....G.
    0040 - 3c ec 0a 05 97 d7 11 bd-65 fd 0c 8e 49 e2 4d 2b   <.......e...I.M+
    0050 - eb c9 49 e4 94 d4 b1 b4-f9 da 09 54 fc 3d 87 ca   ..I........T.=..
    0060 - 06 4d 36 e9 98 c7 95 90-0c 93 79 05 c1 65 b4 4e   .M6.......y..e.N
    0070 - 2c 78 38 6f 1f 72 84 5f-0d 3f 8b 9d dd 71 78 94   ,x8o.r._.?...qx.
    0080 - de c4 10 4f e2 a2 76 c1-e6 c5 7d 1b 1f 19 30 e6   ...O..v...}...0.
    0090 - 86 27 f6 32 c7 5a c8 23-ce ff 9a 91 f6 1f 1c a7   .'.2.Z.#........
    00a0 - 14 38 c9 50 3d 8b fb d9-e4 a1 01 4e bb 25 00 f0   .8.P=......N.%..
    00b0 - cf 85 71 6f 6e 6b 5a ef-43 4a 6d a0 b3 01 33 8a   ..qonkZ.CJm...3.
    00c0 - 1b 10 30 bb c5 3e 32 b3-84 d0 eb 18 e4 64 21 f2   ..0..>2......d!.
    00d0 - ad c3 ff 68 34 b6 76 87-66 22 3c 1e 5d c6 f6 a6   ...h4.v.f"<.]...

    Start Time: 1693286774
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: yes
```

ALSO The issue is not in python-requests since I reproduce it with urllib3

> import urllib3 from urllib3.connectionpool import HTTPSConnectionPool
> conn = HTTPSConnectionPool('selfsigned.xython.fr',
> ca_certs='./selfsigned.xython.fr.crt', cert_reqs='REQUIRED')
> r = conn.request('GET', 'https://selfsigned.xython.fr')

```
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='selfsigned.xython.fr', port=None) Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line
> 467, in _make_request
>     self._validate_conn(conn)   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line
> 1092, in _validate_conn
>     conn.connect()   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 642,
> in connect
>     sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
>                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 783,
> in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
>     ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
>                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 469, in
> ssl_wrap_socket
>     ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
>                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
> File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line
> 513, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
>     return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
>     return self.sslsocket_class._create(
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1108, in _create
>     self.do_handshake()   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1379, in do_handshake
>     self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname
> mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'selfsigned.xython.fr'.
> (_ssl.c:1010)
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line
> 790, in urlopen
>     response = self._make_request(
>                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line
> 491, in _make_request
>     raise new_e urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname
> mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'selfsigned.xython.fr'.
> (_ssl.c:1010)
> 
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/cpp/xython/./testr.py", line 32, in <module>
>     r = conn.request('GET', 'https://selfsigned.xython.fr')
>         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/_request_methods.py", line
> 110, in request
>     return self.request_encode_url(
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/_request_methods.py", line
> 143, in request_encode_url
>     return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line
> 874, in urlopen
>     return self.urlopen(
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line
> 874, in urlopen
>     return self.urlopen(
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line
> 874, in urlopen
>     return self.urlopen(
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line
> 844, in urlopen
>     retries = retries.increment(
>               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 515,
> in increment
>     raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='selfsigned.xython.fr', port=None): Max
> retries exceeded with url: https://selfsigned.xython.fr (Caused by
> SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, "[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
> certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid
> for 'selfsigned.xython.fr'. (_ssl.c:1010)")))
```

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve]. If you can update your question to show us the actual fqdn you're using in your request along with the output of `openssl x509 -in pathtomycat.crt -noout -text` we can probably help you out. Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: If you skip the `verify=verify` parameter, does it fly?

Comment: If I remove verify=verify I got: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='selfsigned.xython.fr', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1010)')))

Comment: You have many questions in here. The root is that this isn't an issue with requests. If you used just Python's standard `socket` module with `ssl`, you would get the same error. Your certificate does not specify a subjectAlternativeName (SAN) and that may help you, but you also need to provide the output of your `openssl s_client -connect` call because I suspect you're not reading that output correctly

Comment: Thanks, nowI have added openssl s_client output

Comment: I found the start of a solution; adding a DNS altname, with the same name, the hostname is now accepted.
Now I want to know why this is mandatory and why some tool accept the certificate (like openssl s_client and firefox) and why some wont (like qualys ssl scan).


It seems that without the altname, the client ask the default vhost and so the hostname is different...

Comment: @montjoie https://serverfault.com/questions/747525/what-does-verify-return1-mean-in-the-openssl-output I suspected it, but openssl is _not_ verifying your certificate based on that output you have `verify return:1` which means it was not ok.

Answer (score 0):

It was kind of surprising for me, but the reason was that CName in certificate isn't enough for Python to verify my server's cert as valid. I also needed to have an alternative name (SAN) added when creating a cert for that server. Afterwards clients were able to use my server.

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -nodes -out my.crt -keyout my.key -addext "subjectAltName=DNS:myhostname.fqdn" -subj "/O=mycompany/CN=myhostname.fqdn"
```